# permanent redirect 301 for using regex for wordpress

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I moved corephp based site to wordpress site and changed its domain name also. urls are save in database. For SEO and other purpose I want to permanent redirect old urls to new urls.
url sample for old php site was like :

```
/article/edleman-japan-names-rowbury-president
```

url sample for new site is like:

```
http://newdomain.com/edleman-japan-names-rowbury-president
```

How can I permanent redirect 301 thourgh .htaccess using regular expression only because I have 10000 urls saved in my db.

Here is the sample for .htaccess file :

```
Redirect 301 /myfolder/article/edleman-japan-names-rowbury-president
```

Any help is greatly appriciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking fr..

Comment: Use [RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) directive.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Starkeen, I used RedirectMatch in .htacces to accomplish this.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/article/edleman-japan-names-rowbury-president/([A-Za-z0-9_-]*) http://target.url.com/$1
```

Above will work for me